# Batch file downloading using Perl or any other language

Tags: python, perl, batch-file, download

I have pretty good knowledge in JS, HTML, CSS, C, C++ and C#.  I have this website which offers question papers for us school students, but to download those we have to visit every page and it's too hard for us.  There are about 150 files. So... ;)

The download links always look like this:

```
http://www.example.com/content/download_content.php?content_id=#
```

where # is a number.

So I thought if javascript or perl or python or any other language can download the files and save it locally automatically.  Currently I don't need much, just the basic code.  I'll learn the language and then I'll develop on it myself.  So please help me out pals..

Answer (score 3):

That's how I usually do such things in bash:

```
for i in `seq 1 1000` ; do wget "http://www.example.com/content/download_content.php?content_id=$i" -O $i.html ; done
```

**UPDATE** Since the URLs point to more than one file type, you could use the `file` command to identify the type of a downloaded file, and adjust the extension accordingly:

```
for i in `seq 1 1000`
do
   wget "http://www.example.com/content/download_content.php?content_id=$i" -O $i.out
   mime=`file --brief --mime-type $i.out`
   if [ "$mime" == "application/pdf" ]
   then
      mv $i.out $i.pdf
   elif [ "$mime" == "application/vnd.ms-office" ]
   then
      mv $i.out $i.doc
   fi
done
```

Comment: bash-3.x knows {1..150} :) - but i like your solution most ;) Cheers

Comment: It seems this code saves the web pages as html..
-o $i.html
Correct me if I'm wrong...
???
What does the code do actually?

Comment: @Ravi: This is shell script code. It looks conformant, so bash or any other POSIX shell will run it. The web page is saved as `$i.html`, where $i is a number in the sequence from (in this case) 1 to 1000. Each iteration of the loop increments the value of `$i`, so you would get `1.html` and `2.html` all the way up to `1000.html`.

Comment: But in the link I've given, a file is got with the php get function (the question mark), so the result is not a webpage but a file (in this case either a doc or a pdf).  So saving it as a webpage is useless.  I want a code to save the file as such in a directory.  Is the other answer right?

Comment: You can choose any name and extension you like: simply replace `$i.html` with `$i.pdf` in order to get file names like `1.pdf`, `2.pdf`, etc.

Comment: @Fritschy Nice, didn't know this one. Thanks!

Comment: @Bolo Can't it automatically choose an extension? 'cos the files may either be doc or pdf...

Comment: @Ravi It's possible to write a program that will rename the files accordingly.  Check my updated answer for an example.

Answer (score 2):

This will do it in shell script using the wget program, dumping them all into the current directory:

```
#!/bin/sh
i=1
while [ $i -le 150 ]; do
  wget -O $i.out "http://www.example.com/content/download_content.php?content_id=$i"
  i = $((i + 1))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using curl instead:

```
curl -O http://www.example.com/content/download_content.php?content_id=#[1-150]
```

Should work on most linux distros and if its not there you can download curl from here: http://curl.haxx.se/ or with a '`apt-get install curl`'

Comment: Oh, will this work fine?  Will it download the files whether it is a doc or a pdf..??